# Weird bone rotation in copyRotation Constraint

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

I'm having a problem with this bone setup I've made. The Thing is, the bones in Y axis rotate as it is supposed to, but when in the X axis, it inverts and I really don't know why. Some images to explain:

[image]
[image]

I want the X axis bones to make the same movement as the ones in the y axis

Comment: I'm not sure, but you should try set World Space to Local Space

Comment: Under the armature object data, panel display, click Axes to true and inspect carefully.  The axis does matter. Is your goal to get a simple open and close of the box or to drive the action via a third bone?

Comment: just openning the box

Comment: Ok just did with local space to local with parent. Eheh thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Consider two separate bones .. one for x-axis rotation, one for y-axis rotation.
- Consider pose space to pose space.
- Consider keyframe of pose